# Automate/Integrate Gmail Apps Script that needs a document for OAuth2?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, oauth-2.0

I wrote a Google Apps Script that takes a certain Gmail Label and forwards all mails (subjects) to my todo list (toodledo).

For the auth I had to use oauth2:
https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2

As this needs the user to manually confirm the authorization, I had to add it in a document because otherwise I cannot call **DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);**

This means I cannot run it like a cronjob. **Can anyone tell me how I could best "deploy" this so it is easily usable from Gmail and I can trigger it after I have sorted my Email?** I'm not sure if I can bind it to Gmail instead of the drive document I used for now.

Note: On http://api.toodledo.com/3/account/index.php it says that I can store the token - however, as I need the user to confirm for the initial authorization, I still cannot run it without a document.

Answer (score 0):

if you use document only for store the oauth2 token, why not use ScriptProperties?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I need it for displaying html: "As this needs the user to manually confirm the authorization, I had to add it in a document because otherwise I cannot call DocumentApp.getUi().showSidebar(page);"

Comment: then maybe you could try to use HtmlService? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to just output the authorization URL to the log, and throw an error so that you get notified.

The examples basically contain this: https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/tree/master/samples